# Limite de envio de mensagens

Tags: phpmailer

Estou criando um sistema que possuí uma confirmação de cadastro. Andei pesquisando algumas hospedagens e vi que algumas ou quase todas que pesquisei possuí limite de envio de mensagens: tem uma hospedagem que limita até 200 emails/hora; outra 500 emails/hora.

Então como faço se existir 1000 cadastros por hora, significa que 800 ou 500  pessoas que se cadastraram NÃO irão receber o email de confirmação de cadastro?

Será que um Servidor VPS resolveria o problema ou eu entendi errado o limite de envio?

*Obs: utilizei a classe "phpMailer" para envio das mensagens.*

Comment: Vai depender da empresa que fornece o VPS. Caso você precise trabalhar com muitos envios, recomendo usar ferramentas para envio em massa, por exemplo https://www.mandrill.com/pricing/

Comment: Realmente vai manter o registo de 1000 novos registos por hora? Se assim for e se necessitar de manter o servidor com restrições pode armazenar os emails, e fazer um cron para os ir enviando.